# Any homeomorphism is a covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

**Prove that any homeomorphism is a covering map.**

My thought:

Let $p:X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism. Choose $y\in Y$. Then $Y$ is a open neighbourhood of $y$. Since $p$ is a homeomorphism, $p^{-1}(Y)=X$ is an open set and also homeomorphic to $Y$.
Am I correct? Please give me your valuable suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it seems correct, and also $X$ is open because it is the whole space, and of course you then have $f_| X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism, and the same argument holds for any {$y$}..

Comment: The definition of covering space involve a statement like, "for each point, there exists a neighborhood around it such that ........". For a homeomorphism, the condition will be satisfied with the full space being the required open set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct: You have shown that each $y\in Y$ has an open neighborhood $Y$ whose preimage is a disjoint union of open sets (here $X$) each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $Y$ via $p$.